# node.js export calling another controller method within controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to call a method controller B, says it's conB.js and look like this

```
module.exports.verify = function(req,res,next){

}
```

Then now I'm in conA.js, how can I call verify of conB and pass arguments to it?

I know firstly I have to include it,

```
var ConB = require('ConB');
// but then?
```

Answer (score 0):

The ConB object will contain the exports from that controller so you just call the method on be object

```
ConB.verify(...)
```